# How to build wxmathPlot for win32?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, wxwidgets, wxmathplot

I downloaded the latest [wxmathplot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net/) but the readme is a bit sparse with instructions on how to build on win32 platform.

Has anyone used this library for win32?  Can someone point me to the docs or give some hints/advice on how to build for win32 targets.

We'll eventually use this for cross platform stuff, for now it is just win32 until we port our other code.

I presume I have to use CMake, but have not used it before and it is not obvious to me how to build this all - I have already installed CMake, but I am apparently too stupid to figure out how to build this library/samples.

Well, I managed to make an SLN file, but it was not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use wxMathPlot.  I simply add mathplot.cpp and mathplot.h to the MSVS2008 C++ projects that need to use it.  This compiles and links without my having to do anything special.

Comment: This worked for me.  The cmake stuff is nice, but you are right - I don't need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a partial answer - to get
>   CMake to build an sln file:
>
> Well, unfortunately there is no good
>   documentation on how to build
>   wxMathPlot on Windows, but it is very
>   simple. Just use CMake:
>
> http://www.cmake.org/
>
> Download and install it, then open
>   CMake gui, selecting the directory
>   where you uncompressed wxMathPlot and
>   a target build directory. click
>   Configure twice and then click
>   Generate. CMake does all its magic and
>   you'll get project files to build
>   wxMathPlot depending on your compiler.
>   For example, if you use Visual Studio,
>   a solution sln file is generated: open
>   it and build.

That works for building an sln file

Comment: You did right, and the procedure is fine. One has to take into an account how the wxWidgets are built on the machine and change the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS accordingly (if necessary). I'm refering to /MT,etc. flags. Hope it helps. Btw, the wxwidgets' site has an excellent wiki(http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_WxWidgets_on_Windows)