# Errors Compiling wxMathPlot

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, wxmathplot

this is following on from this question posted previously:

[How to build wxmathPlot for win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500495/how-to-build-wxmathplot-for-win32)

The best answer says to just add the mathplot.h and mathplot.cpp files to your project and then it should work.

however, after I add these 2 files to my project in visual studios 2010 (by right-clicking my project->add->existing item and selecting the 2 files) and try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
1>  mathplot.cpp
1>mathplot.cpp(133): warning C4100: 'event' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>mathplot.cpp(133): warning C4100: 'w' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>mathplot.cpp(278): warning C4100: 'event' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>mathplot.cpp(278): warning C4100: 'w' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>mathplot.cpp(2239): warning C4996: 'wxImage::SaveFile': was declared deprecated
1>mathplot.cpp(2610): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2610): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2610): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2610): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2749): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2749): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2749): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2749): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2750): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2750): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2750): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2750): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2751): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2751): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2751): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2751): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2763): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2763): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2763): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2763): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2847): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2847): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2847): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2847): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>mathplot.cpp(2877): error C2589: 'if' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2877): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>mathplot.cpp(2877): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>mathplot.cpp(2877): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathplot.cpp file, I have changed all 
**::wxLogError** with **wxLogError**

and comment out the line **#define new DEBUG_NEW**, then it compiles successfully.

Comment: wxLogError is actually a preprocessor macro that starts with an "if (..", so
    ::if(
will cause a syntax error.

Redefining new with the preprocessor is also pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

As wxmathplot is light weight library, it contains only 2 files, the .h and the .cpp, I found it very simple and very easy to just copy the .h file to my include directory and the .cpp file to my project src folder and compile the project as a whole. I posted a repository on GitHub with modified wxmathplot where I moved all the includes to the header file, so you only need to include mathplot.h in your project. linke [here!](https://github.com/HZine/wxMathPlot).